# How to vertically center content of child divs inside parent div in a fluid layout

Tags: html, css

I have a div which contains two child divs, and they are intended to be part of fluid layout, so I can't set a fixed size for them in px.

There are two goals here:

1. Align the two child divs horizontally, which I have achieved using `float: left` and `float: right` respectively.
2. Vertically center the text (within the child divs) relative to the parent div. The text is short and takes a single line by design.

What I have now: http://jsfiddle.net/yX3p9/

Apparently, the two child divs do not take the full height of the parent div, and therefore their text are not vertically centered relative to the parent div.

Conceptually, to achieve the goals above, we can either make the child divs vertically centered within the parent div, or we can make the child divs take the full height of the parent div. What is the robust way to do so?

*Browser support: IE 9+ and other usual modern browsers.

Comment: If you want to take two child height to be full length of div then you can use height:100% !important.. but even that doesnt align the contents to center

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yX3p9/7/

I used `display: table-cell;` in order to use `vertical-align: middle;`

Comment: You could set the line-height to the parent div. But in your case, the parent has a percentage as height, so you can't do that. A line-height of 100% would mean that the line should have the same height as the text.

Answer (score 54):

I prefer the usage of transform above the above answers.

```
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
-moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
-o-transform: translateY(-50%);
```

In my experience it works in many situations and on all major browsers (**even IE9+**).

If you use SCSS, you might even like to implement this mixin:

```
@mixin v-align($position: absolute){
    position: $position;  top: 50%;  
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform:translateY(-50%); /* IE */
    -moz-transform:translateY(-50%); /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transform:translateY(-50%); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform:translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Thanks- this one worked where all else failed. Cheers!

Comment: Simple and elegant solution. Thank you.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. In my case, I just had to add "position:relative" to the first block of code. Cheers.

Answer (score 7):

Use `line-height`. If it's just one line of text, a high line-height will effectively position the text in the middle of the line.

Or try `display:table-cell` in combination with `vertical-align`.

Comment: how does `line-height` work in this scenario? Tried `display:table-cell` and `vertical-align`, but didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to using CSS tables, you can also use absolute positioning to get a similar layout.

Using your HTML as is (no extra elements), apply the following CSS:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.parent {
    background-color: grey;
    height: 20%;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    min-height: 1.6em;
    position: relative;
}
.left, .right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -0.8em;
}
.left {
    background-color: yellow;
    padding-left: 20px;
    left: 0;
}
.right {
    background-color: red;
    padding-right: 20px;
    right: 0;
}
```

You can see the demo fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/cByHa/

In the `.parent` container, set the line-height to an explicit value (1.6em as the font size), `position: relative` and `min-height` to maintain enough height for the text.

The two child elements `.left` and `.right` are positioned absolutely with `top: 50%`
and use `margin-top: -0.8em` to get vertical centering (use one-half of line-height value).

Use the left and right offsets (or padding) to adjust the child elements horizontal position as needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
    html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.parent {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: grey;
    font-size: 1.6em;
}

.left {
    margin-left: 2%;
    float: left;
    background-color: yellow;
    height:100%;   
}

.right {
    margin-right: 2%;
    float: right;
    background-color: red;
    height:100%;    
}
.parent span{
    display:table;
    height:100%;
}
.parent em{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yX3p9/13/

Answer (score 0):

Make Height and Width as 100% in child element. This was the child will occupy entire space of parent and `vertical-align:middle` property will work. I used it in a case when parent was a `<div>` and child was a `<table>`. Table was marked to take height and width as 100%.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="position:relative;white-space:nowrap">
  <img style="visibility:hidden; width:1px; height:100%; verticle-align:middle" />
  <img src="the-image-url" style="position:relative;left:-1px;" />
</div>
```

This should work.