# Set the position of a <div> block in the middle of the page with adjusting its height automatically

Tags: html, css

I want to make a `<div>` block which width is 100% and set its position in the middle of the page (horizontal & vertical center), but without setting an exact height number (because I don't know the exact number of `<div>` height).

Here's my code:

```css
#content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="content">Hello world!</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

The result will be like:

[image]

(It set its height to an explicit 100% automatically.)

But what I want is like:

[image]

I know I need to specify an exact number of height to achieve this effect. But now I don't know the exact height of the content, because the height of the content should be variable.

So how can I make the height adjust itself automatically?

Comment: is this what you are going for? https://plnkr.co/edit/a0lruDZV1OpvsAtjaOEQ?p=info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Flex-box` that's it

Here is the working **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/m45w2s54/1/)**

PS: Try to avoid `position: absolute` if you can done that with other properties.

```css
#content {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
body{
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">Hello world!</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `transform: translateY(-50%);` with `top: 50%` without specifying any height to achieve this.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="content">Hello world!</div>
```

Comment: This solution is not cross-browser compatible. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32584696/1274398 it's the same idea as yours.

Comment: @BartBurg Check [this](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) All latest browser support `transform` and old browser also support it with vendor prefixes. Support for it will increase in future as well. Those days are gone when we were using table and table-cell layout for aligning.

Comment: You're right I guess, we did have some problems with it lately, but maybe it was with earlier IE browsers.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<style>
#content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height:5%;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}</style>
</head>
 <body>
    <div id="content" style="background-color:rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)">Hello world!</div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#content {
position: absolute;
top: 50%; /* set to 50% of for middle */
left: 0;
right: 0;
/* remove the bottom property */
margin: auto;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
transform: translateY(-50%); /* add transform property to move it up 50% of the div's actual height */
}
```

```css
#content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
    transform: trranslateY(-50%);
   text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  
  <p>Hello world! Pretty simple</p>
  <p>Just set the transform property to subtract 50% of the div's height while positioning it vertical center.</p>
  <p>Position will automatically adjust based on the current height of the div</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use simply css property =

```
#content {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: auto;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);

/******Just Add one line in css its help you******************/

height: auto;
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Use this css style:

```
body{
margin:auto;
}
#content {
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
top: calc(50% - 50px);
}
```